# AFnetworking how to set referer url in the header when to get html from url with get method

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

The URL will return HTTP status code 302 when the referrer url is `nil`.  I set it with the method that how to set cookie, but it's still not working.

My code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
//
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
NSStringEncoding enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding (kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000);

manager.requestSerializer.stringEncoding = enc;
manager.responseSerializer.stringEncoding = enc;

[manager GET:@"XXXX://172.21.96.X6/xskbcx.aspx?xh=1XX24132&xm=XXXXF4&gnmkdm=N121603" parameters:nil
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"huoqushuju: %ld",(long)operation.response.statusCode);
          NSLog(@"数据：%@",operation.responseString);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error debugDescription]);
    }];//获取登陆后的网页
```

The error log:

```
2014-02-19 20:04:32.005 JiaoWuXiTong[3049:70b] Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain      Code=-1011 "Request failed: found (302)" UserInfo=0x8abc7f0    {NSErrorFailingURLKey=XXXX://172.21.96.X6/xskbcx.aspx?xh=1XX24132&xm=XXXXF4&gnmkdm=N121603, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8ccfb30> { URL: XXXX://172.21.96.X6/xskbcx.aspx?xh=1XX24132&xm=XXXXF4&gnmkdm=N121603 } { status code: 302, headers {
"Cache-Control" = private;
"Content-Length" = 117;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=gb2312";
Date = "Wed, 19 Feb 2014 12:04:26 GMT";
Location = "";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/6.0";
"X-AspNet-Version" = "1.1.4322";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: found (302)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `requestSerializer` only encodes parameters that you pass as part of the `parameters` dictionary.

Try something like this instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
parameters[@"xh"] = @"1XX24132";
parameters[@"xm"] = @"XXXXF4";
parameters[@"gnmkdm"] = @"N121603";

NSURL *url = // URL for your web API end point

[manager GET:url parameters:parameters
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // ...
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // ...
}];
```

Comment: I try this,But it add the parameter in the url.It is wrong.

Comment: Please show the code where you've set added parameters to a `parameters` dictionary then.

Comment: Do you literally have `GET://XXX`... that is, the `XXXX://` string, or are you using `HTTP` / `HTTPS` or another correct protocol?  ?

Comment: I use HTTP,I can't put too many link in  stack overflow,so I change the real url to xxxx.

Comment: I Tried your method,But the encoding is useless,I can not add this manager.requestSerializer.stringEncoding = enc;..POST method is ok..

Comment: What do you mean by `POST method is ok` ? Does it work if you use `POST` instead of `GET` ? If so, is your end point setup expecting parameters to be sent `POST` to it then?